# Set image color in SwipeAction

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-swipeactions

I'm trying to customise color of icon in `swipeAction` of SwiftUI. Outside `foregroundColor()` it works, inside, - not.

```
            Button {
                print("Hello")
            } label: {
                Label(
                    title: {},
                    icon: {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .foregroundColor(.purple) // It makes checkmark red
                    }
                )
            }

            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                Text("Text").swipeActions {
                    Button {
                        print("Hello")
                    } label: {
                        Label(
                            title: {},
                            icon: {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    .foregroundColor(.purple) // It doesn't change anything
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

A swipe action has its own styling that is applied by the system.  According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/swipeactions(edge:allowsfullswipe:content:)):

> For labels or images that appear in swipe actions, SwiftUI
> automatically applies the fill symbol variant

You can add color by adding the `.tint()` modifier.

```
Text("Text").swipeActions {
    Button {
        print("Hello")
    } label: {
        Label("Choose", systemImage: "checkmark")
    }
    .tint(.green)
}
```

---

[image: Showing tint color in simulator]

---

**Note**: The color red is used by default for destructive actions (like delete) and should be avoided for non-destructive actions. If your action is destructive, use `Button(role: .destructive)` and the system will color it red if you don’t apply `.tint()`.

Check the documentation for more information about [swipeActions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/swipeactions(edge:allowsfullswipe:content:)).

Comment: Please, notice that I'm trying to customise ICON color but not the background

Comment: iOS achieves a clean consistent look by enforcing certain styling rules. Here, they want you to use the filled look for swipe actions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how I did it, but it is a workaround:

You can use `UIImage` instead of `Image`, tint it as `alwaysOriginal` and convert to `Image` again. Here is the basic code example:

```swift
 Image(uiImage: UIImage(named:"your_image")!.withTintColor(.purple, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal))
```

P.S. It will work also with colors from your palette which may support light/dark mode switching, etc.

EDIT: I used code above instead of Label